# Is there an example of a 2-generated finite metabelian group with abelianization $C_n^2$ which is not generated by two elements of order $n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose $G$ is a finite two-generated metabelian group with abelianization $C_n\times C_n$.

> Can one find an example of such a $G$ which cannot be generated by two elements of order $n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$Q_8$ and, more generally, the generalized quaternion groups $Q_{2^k}$  are examples. They are metabelian, their abelianization is $C_2 \times C_2$, and they have a unique element of order $2$.

You can construct example with $n=2m$ for $m$ odd by taking a direct product $Q_{2^k} \times C_m \times C_m$.

It is possible that there are no examples with $n$ odd.